# Fancyhdr Pagenumbering at chapter

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, scrbook, headline

I have the following problem. I need a header in my master thesis. I have a template for that. The fancyhdr package has problems with scrbook. Now I have found the following solution:

```
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
%\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }{}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\sffamily\thepage}
%\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\sffamily\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\sffamily\bfseries\leftmark}

\fancypagestyle{headings}{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{

}

%\fancypagestyle{empty}{
%  \fancyhf{}
%  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%}
```

However, I only get a numbering, when a chapter begins. Can someone help a newbie?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use both packages `scrlayer-scrpage` and `fancyhdr` in the same document. With a KOMA-Script class `scrlayer-scrpage` is recommended.

I do not know how the desired layout looks like, but may be the following helps:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftmark}%<- changed
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}%<- changed
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{\chapapp\ \thechapter. \ }% <- changed

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But if you decide to use `fancyhdr`, then remove all `scrlayer-scrpage` code from your document.